How do I get PrimeVue to style InputText
Probably similar to Primevue Textarea is not styled but I am using CDN.  When using the more complex components like p-calendar it is styled but the simplest input component InputText does not seem to style at all.
https://jsfiddle.net/970nwp6e/
Here's the code


<html>

  <head>
    <link href="//unpkg.com/primevue@3.52.0/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@3.2.33/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/primevue@3.52.0/core/core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/primevue@3.52.0/inputtext/inputtext.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <p-inputtext v-model="text"></p-inputtext>
      <h1>
        {{ text }}
      </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const {
      createApp,
      ref
    } = Vue
    const App = {
      setup() {
        const text = ref("")
        return {
          text
        }
      }
    }
    createApp(App)
     .use(primevue.config.default)
     .component('p-inputtext', primevue.inputtext)
     .mount("#app")

  </script>

</html>




The more I look at it the more this appears to be a bug in the current versions of PrimeVue.  https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/5709
